# 301 URL Redirection with value

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need help regarding URL redirection

I want to set a affiliate url like `localhost/mysite/bussname/proname`, when a viewer will see this link and click it it will redirect to

```
localhost/mysite/mypage.php?bussinessname=bussname&productname=proname
```

I already use this code

```
Redirect 301 localhost/mysite/bussname/pagname localhost/mysite/mypage.php?bussinessname=bussname&productname=proname
```

It causes internal server URL.

So, what will be the possible code in htaccess. Please help me, thanks in previous.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^mysite/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /mysite/mypage.php?bussinessname=$1&productname=$2 [L,QSA]
```

You'll need to make sure you have `AllowOverride Fileinfo` or `AllowOverride All` in the server config for your document root, and that mod_rewrite is loaded. Then the rules need to go in an htaccess file in your document root.

If you have relative links in your page's content, you may need to change them to absolute URLs or add this to the page's header:

```
<base href="/mysite/"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the users to see the new url, you should use redirecting:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^mysite/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /mysite/mypage.php?bussinessname=$1&productname=$2 [R=301,L]
```

otherwise, if you do not want them to see the new url, you should use rewriting:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^mysite/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /mysite/mypage.php?bussinessname=$1&productname=$2 [L]
```

Both codes should be placed inside the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your webhost, which should start with the line `RewriteEngine ON`